# Eclipse: java.lang.RuntimeException: Application “org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench” could not be found in the registry

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Iam using helios eclipse (eclipse-SDK-3.6.1-win32).
I update this `Helps > Check of updates`
I have updated completely by checking all. (Most of them was plugin related to android)
After completion of updates, it asked me to restart eclipse. After that, when ever i start eclipse it shows error. It shows the following dialog

```
An error has occurred. See the log file
D:\eclipse-SDK-3.6.1-win32\eclipse\configuration\11003434.log.
```

That log is

```
!SESSION 2011-05-11 12:06:34.453 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-05-11 12:06:36.593
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-05-11 12:06:36.593


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-05-11 12:06:36.687
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director.app.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.legacytestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplicationnonmain, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.nonuithreadtestapplication, org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate, org.eclipse.update.core.siteOptimizer, org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.generator.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, org.eclipse.pde.build.Build.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

I didn't understand anything.
Can anyone help me in this.
I'm really stuck

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running `eclipse.exe -clean`?

> Any cached data used by the OSGi
>   framework and eclipse runtime will be
>   wiped clean. This will clean the
>   caches used to store bundle dependency
>   resolution and eclipse extension
>   registry data. Using this option will
>   force eclipse to reinitialize these
>   caches.

Comment: I had similar problem and this fixed it. I've been running Photon on Ubuntu for months without problems but this morning it crashed. When I tried to restart, I got pop-up pointing me to the log file which identified problem as `java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry`. Re-installing didn't fix the problem but `eclipse.exe -clean` did. Thanks :)

Answer (score -3):

its clearly saying that some dependcies plugins were not been installed, so please reslove the dependency .

Better you post the same in Eclipse forum, they will provide you solution.

Comment: `"org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry`- Eclipse itself is not found (which makes no sense)